# Visualisar interface da box na virtualbox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Como usar a interface da máquina virtual, e não somente pelo terminal de comandos?

Segue o link do meu vagrantfile:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fbd8f17a0a85ff4c223c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer usar a interface da máquina virtual, e não apenas interagir com ela por meio da linha de comando (após executar `vagrant ssh`), certo?

Normalmente as máquinas virtuais são *headless*, o que significa que são inicializadas sem a UI (interface de usuário). Para inicializar a UI da VM, basta adicionar a seguinte configuração no `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

Comment: Já fiz isso mas a box não aparece quando abro o virtualbox entende?

Comment: Já entendi o seu problema. Vou complementar a resposta.

Comment: Nesse caso eu preciso configurar algo na própria interface do virtualbox, ou só acrescentar essa configuração que você colocou ai no vagrantfile?

Comment: @Faro É só colocar a configuração.

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, será que falta algo além disso para acrescentar no vagrantfile?

Comment: Até onde eu sei é só isso mesmo. Você rodou um `vagrant down` e um `vagrant up`, ou simplesmente um `vagrant reload`, depois disso?

Comment: Resolvido caro.